# If Stament returns null

Tags: java, android

Firts codes works well..
But second codes gives error as:
**java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference**

*Working Code:*

```
String dnt = model.getDonut;
     if (dnt != null) {
            if (!dnt.equals("")) {
      //Do sth
                }
            }
```

*Not Working Code:*

```
String dnt = model.getDonut;
     if (dnt != null || !dnt.equals("")) {
      //Do sth
            }
```

Comment: `||` is a shortcircuit logical-or. We need an shortcircuit logical-and `&&` in this case. As an aside: a statement cannot return anything.

Comment: Ahh. great. Thanks.